# Faceting hibernate search results by Instant range fails

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have an entity with indexed creation timestamp of `java.time.Instant` type and I'd like to facet search results by creation timestamp range.
The entity looks the following way:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Document {

    @Id
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String name;

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    @Facet
    private Instant creationTimestamp;
}
```

When I start my application I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000264: @Facet is not supported for type 'java.time.Instant'. See org.hibernate.search.bugs.Document#creationTimestamp
```

I haven't found anything related to faceting by Instant value in [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.8).

Is it possible to facet hibernate search results by creation timestamp range?

I've created a failing test case here: [github repo link](https://github.com/IlyaZinkovich/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/instant-facet/search/hibernate-search-lucene/src/test/java/org/hibernate/search/bugs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid Java 8 date/time types are not yet supported in the Hibernate Search faceting subsystem. I created an ticket to address this, but I can't say when we will (there are internal complications): https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2954

**UPDATE**: Facets on date/time types are supported in Hibernate Search 6 with aggregations, which replace Hibernate Search 5 facets.
[Getting started with Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started), [Aggregations in Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-aggregation).

In the meantime, you can work around this lack of support by using a `@Transient` long field representing the timestamp:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Document {

    @Id
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String name;

    private Instant creationTimestamp;

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    @Facet
    @javax.persistence.Transient
    public Long getCreationForFaceting() {
        return creationTimestamp == null ? null : creationTimestamp.toEpochMilli();
    }
}
```

And then querying using long timestamps too.

Not an ideal solution by a long shot, but it's the only one I can think of.